# Why does my DFS Cycle Detection in graph always return true?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I recently read about cycle detection in graphs using dfs and decided to implement it. Using an adjacency list, my code ran awesome(ly), so I decided to solve an actual problem using the skills. Here's [the problem I chose](http://codeforces.com/contest/510/problem/B). But, the reason I ended up at SO is because my code even fails to solve the sample cases correctly and always seems to return true(not really odd, must be some silly bug...).

For the question, the approach I used was to run a dfs(depth first search) and check if we revisit a visited node again. I run exhaustive dfs, ie. I check every unvisited node for checking. To ensure that the distance between the vertices in the undirected graph is atlas 4, I keep track of the recursive stack and the levels of pdfs tree visited till very node in the tree(using tmp_recursive_stack and recursion_stack, I have an intuitive feeling they are the root cause of the problem), and build up on progress, but onfortunately, the code fails to perform. Atacched below is the code and the test case on which it fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int n, m;
vector<string> matrice;
vector< vector<bool> > flag;
int recursion_stack = 0;

void dfs(int i, int j)
{
    if(!flag[i][j])
    {
        flag[i][j] = true;
        recursion_stack++;
        int tmp_rec_stack = recursion_stack;
        if(j > 0)
        {
            if(matrice[i][j] == matrice[i][j-1])
            {
                if(flag[i][j-1] && recursion_stack >= 3)
                {
                    cout << "Yes\n"; exit(0);
                }

                dfs(i, j-1);
            }

        }
        recursion_stack = tmp_rec_stack;
        if(j < m-1)
        {
            if(matrice[i][j] == matrice[i][j+1])
            {
                if(flag[i][j+1] && recursion_stack >= 3)
                {
                    cout << "Yes\n"; exit(0);
                }

                dfs(i, j+1);
            }
        }
        recursion_stack = tmp_rec_stack;
        if(i < n-1)
        {
            if(matrice[i][j] == matrice[i+1][j])
            {
            if(flag[i+1][j] && recursion_stack >= 3)
                {
                    cout << "Yes\n"; exit(0);
                }

                dfs(i+1, j);
            }
        }
        recursion_stack = tmp_rec_stack;
        if(i > 0)
        {
            if(matrice[i][j] == matrice[i-1][j])
            {
                if(flag[i-1][j] && recursion_stack >= 3)
                {
                    cout << "Yes\n"; exit(0);
                }

                dfs(i-1, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    matrice.clear(); matrice.resize(n);
    flag.clear(); flag.resize(n, vector<bool>(m, false));
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) cin >> matrice[i];

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < m;j++)
        {
            if(!flag[i][j])
            {
                dfs(i, j);
                recursion_stack = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "No\n";
}
```

The test case that fails:

```
IN
3 4
AAAA
ABCA
AADA
```

Expected out:

```
No
```

My Out:

```
Yes
```

Comment: Using meaningful variable names would help a lot with understanding what's happening here.  Using single letters makes things a bit cryptic for the casual observer.  Your DFS function isn't very reusable if it exits the application.  Consider how you might return the result so that `main()` is responsible for printing the affirmative result.

Comment: Possibly the reason that it's failing is that your 'visited' flags are all getting set but never cleared.  You'll want to clear the flags after each call to `dfs`, since you're running a new DFS from a new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You algorithm is incorrect. Here is a very simple example: `AAA`. Let's assume that you run the depth first search from the leftmost position. When it reaches the rightmost `A`, the `recursion_stack` is 3. So when it checks the `(i, j - 1)` cell(which is the second `A`), it finds a cycle which doesn't exist. How to fix it? Well, the easiest way to go is to implement a proper algorithm for finding cycles instead of trying to fix this one. Here is pseudo code of a correct solution:

```
hasCycle = false
visited = an empty set

dfs(node, parent)
    visited.add(node)
    for child <- children(node)
         if not child in visited
             dfs(child, node)
         else if child != parent
             hasCycle = true

for node <- nodes
    if not node in visited
        dfs(node, node) // we can also use a fictive value for a parent like null
print hasCycle
```

It is correct because it finds some cycle in a graph and there are no cycles with less than 4 vertices in this problem(due to the way the graph is constructed).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to teach me. I mean, can you explain the pseudocode better or give me some links to pages that can teach me ?

Comment: @Nib You can read about it here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/ (it says pretty much the same thing as my pseudoe code, but note the code there is not really good: it leaks memory and uses pointers for no good reason).